# Equal angles in the circumcircle mid-arc triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, triangle-centres

I have "discovered" this property while playing with the circumscribed circle of a triangle in GeoGebra.

Let $ABC$ be a triangle, $A'$, $B'$, $C'$ the intersections of the corresponding angle bisectors and perpendicular bisectors of $ABC$, opposite to $A$, $B$, and $C$ accordingly.

Then the angle bisectors and perpendicular bisectors of $ABC$ divide the angles of the triangle $A'B'C'$ into three parts, two of which, adjacent to the sides of $A'B'C'$, are equal.

[image: Angles of the circumcircle triangle]

Questions:

1. Is there a name for the triangle $A'B'C'$?
2. How to prove the equality of the angles?

Comment: According to **Wolfram MathWorld**, it's called the [*circumcircle mid-arc triangle*](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircumcircleMid-ArcTriangle.html).

Comment: An illustration in GeoGebra: https://www.geogebra.org/m/dwhhxztv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the crucial part of your post is to note the fact that **$A'$, $B'$, and $C'$ lie on the circumcircle of the triangle**, which is not very hard to be proved (just note that if, for instance, $C'$ is the intersection of the perpendicular bisector of $AB$ and the circumcircle, then $AC'=C'B$). Having this fact, some angle chasing is enough for the second part of your question. For example, according to your image,

$$\angle C'A'O=\angle BA'O -\angle BA'C'=(90^{\circ}-\frac{\angle A}{2})-(\frac{\angle C}{2})=\frac{\angle B}{2}.$$

On the other hand,

$$\angle AA'B'=\angle ABB'=\frac{\angle B}{2}.$$