# Does the sequence of circumcircle mid-arc triangles converge to an equilateral triangle?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, triangle-centres

This is a follow-up question on [The triangle of intersections of angle bisectors and perpendicular bisectors of a triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4683369/427611)

Let $\triangle_1$ be a triangle,
$\triangle_2$ the circumcircle mid-arc triangle of $\triangle_1$,
$\triangle_3$ the circumcircle mid-arc triangle of $\triangle_2$,
...
$\triangle_n$ the circumcircle mid-arc triangle of $\triangle_{n-1}$.

The sequence seems to converges to an equilateral triangle.
Is this true?
How can we prove it?

Comment: Hint: if the triangle has angles $A,B,C$, then its the mid-arc triangle has angles $\frac{A+B}{2}, \frac{B+C}{2},\frac{C+A}{2}$.

Comment: I tried ChatGPT - Here is an answer (partial)   For your example (90,60,30) I do not get an isosceles triangle - I get (45,75,60)
You are correct, and I apologize for my mistake. When constructing the mid-arc triangle for a triangle with angles of 90 degrees, 60 degrees, and 30 degrees, the resulting triangle is indeed a triangle with angles of 45 degrees, 75 degrees, and 60 degrees. Thank you for pointing out my error.

Comment: Continuation:In this case, the mid-arc triangle of this resulting triangle will have angles of approximately 52.5 degrees, 63.75 degrees, and 63.75 degrees, which is an isosceles triangle. If we continue the process of constructing the mid-arc triangle with the resulting triangle, we will oscillate between two isosceles triangles with angles of approximately 53.6 degrees, 63.2 degrees, and 63.2 degrees, and 51.8 degrees, 64.1 degrees, and 64.1 degrees.

So, here, the mid-arc triangles converge to a specific pair of isosceles triangles, but they do not converge to an equilateral triangle.

Comment: @Moti I got a different reply from ChatGPT: "No, the sequence of circumcircle mid-arc triangles does not converge to an equilateral triangle in general.<...>For example, if the initial triangle is a right-angled triangle with legs of length 1 and 2, then the sequence of circumcircle mid-arc triangles will converge to a rectangle with sides of length 1 and 2.<...>Therefore, the convergence of the sequence of circumcircle mid-arc triangles depends on the properties of the initial triangle and cannot be assumed to converge to an equilateral triangle in general."

Comment: You are accepting answers without pointing to the Bot on mistakes. It talks about sides where this is not relevant. You could ask the bot to write for you a program in Python for computing the convergence. In more than 50% of the cases the convergence is to an equilateral triangle.

Comment: @Moti There is no such thing as accepting answers in ChatGPT.

Comment: @Moti I did not want to bring all the garbage coming from ChatGPT during the discussion. That was just one example, there were worse. I assume the current ChatGPT version does not have a proper geometry knowledge base.

Comment: I think I finally got a program right to make the computation and ChatGPT edmitted to be erroneous: :) "I apologize for any confusion I may have caused earlier. You are correct that the iterative process we implemented will always converge to an equilateral triangle, with angles of 60 degrees each.

I must have been mistaken earlier when I said that the process could converge to other triangle configurations.

Thank you for pointing this out, and I apologize for any confusion this may have caused.

Comment: You were right - any three triplets convert to 1/3 of the sums, where the case for a triangle is one specific example where the sum is 180. dxiv suggestion is perfect!